# Repeated continuous action using simple present or present continuous

Tags: ambiguity

What is the difference between the  meaning of the following two sentences.  (One is simple present and the other is continuous present).

1. He works every Saturday.
2. He is working every Saturday.

Answer (score 1):

The difference might be more evident if you reduce the simple present example to "He works Saturdays."  It refers to something habitual, or something routinely recurring that characterizes him or his existence.  It includes the present, but it doesn't address how long it has been going on or how long it will continue.  It's typically associated with long-term situations that become associated with the person.  "Who is Bob?"  "He's the guy who works Saturdays."

"He is working every Saturday" refers to something currently recurring routinely but it's more typically applied to a temporary situation.  He didn't always work every Saturday and expects that it won't be forever; he is currently in that situation filling a temporary role but the situation isn't associated with him, personally.

Answer (score 0):

When I would say "he is working every Saturday" I would be talking about specific Saturdays that I am looking at. For example, if Barbra and I wanted to plan something with Phil in the month a May, Barbra may say "We can't plan anything on Saturday. He is working every Saturday in this month", which makes sense because the present continuous is something that is happening now in a set amount of time.

Saying "he works every Saturday" generally refers to a job he has been doing for a while and that he'll probably work Saturdays for a good deal of months. For example, Mathew's mother tells Bill that there is this great program at Puppy Palace and it runs on Saturdays. Bill would say "I work every Saturday," because Mathew's mother was referring to any Saturday, and not one in a specific time frame. However, Bill could also say "I am working every Saturday", but he would be technically saying that he won't be at Puppy Palace in the near future.

However, for the most part saying "He works every Saturday" and "He is working every Saturday" can be easily interchangeable because of the word "every". Which one should be used is determined solely by the context of the sentence. You would probably not continuously encounter a situation where one of these would be grammatically incorrect because I kept on having to change my sentences so only one of the examples would fit and I still failed at that.

I am sorry. I confused myself and now I am about to pass out on my bed. I talk too much and now I must sacrifice a carrot to the gods in hope that they will post cat videos to Youtube.